# Придебаге проекта asp net mvc появляется ошибка

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

При дебагинге вылазит вот такая ошибка. Проект я перестроила, а толку ноль. Подскажите, пожаулйста, в чем ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте даты dll и pdb файлов в папке bin. Они совпадают с временем последнего перестроения проекта? меняются при перестроении?

Comment: часть файлов dll и pdb меняются,а часть нет

Comment: Если не меняется ZZZZ.Service.pdb и ZZZZ.Service.dll - удалите референсы на него, и добавьте заново, но именно как референсы на проект (через выбор проекта из списка в Projects на диалоге добавления референса а не через browse в его bin/obj)

Comment: Service.pdb и .Service.dll  меняются, выдается ошибка:  http://dropmef‌​iles.com/imlL9

Answer (score 1):

В [обсуждении](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bf105e3b-2da6-4969-9fb5-50f77383f8a1/entering-break-mode-failed-for-the-following-reason-source-file-xxx-does-not-belong-to-the-project?forum=vsdebug) предлагается несколько вариантов решения :) Некоторые размещу ниже.

Способ 1: Выполнить Build -> Clean Solution, а затем Build -> Build Solution.

Способ 2: Закрыть IDE, удалить каталоги bin и obj, а затем перезапустить IDE.

Способ 3: Выполнить Tools -> Import And Export Settings -> Reset all settings.

Comment: Спасибо, отредактировала :)

Comment: Как-то совсем наугад :( Т.е. ошибка может быть вызвана, например, криво стоящим reference на проект сервисов. Все снести и перебилдовать поможет, но только на один раз - сайт будет всегда подтягивать старые dll.

Comment: из обсуждения по вашей ссылке - "However, the "References" of the depending project still showed the path to the old location." - это признак того, что references были проставлены на файлы в bin/obj, а не на проект в solution :(

Comment: Т.е мне необходимо закрыть VS,в папке Web снести  папку bin и obj, затем открыть VS и build project или rebild?

Comment: после удаления bin и obj и ребилде проекта выдает следующую ошибкуhttp://dropmefiles.com/imlL9